# Unable to open link after migration 2013 to 2016 in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]

Unable to open link after migration 2013 to 2016 in sharepoint

Comment: There must be a custom solution with the name `TRNew`. You need to re-install it to make it's DLL available in GAC.

Comment: Which link you are trying to open?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a custom WSP Solution Deployed in your environment, please make sure also migrate this custom solution.